# Function to get IP Address in an Ajax Get Method

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm new to Programming and have this assignment of using JQUERY Ajax method in Javascript to get the data of a Gateway and attach some of it's value to the properties of an object. That I have already done but in the object is an "ip" property and it's value should be the ip in the url in the get request. I have over this for for hours and can't figure it out but i believe there's a simple way to go about it. Below is code and i hope someone out there can help out.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <title>Gateway Object</title>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial- 
   scale=1.0">
   <script src="jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
   <script>
        gateway = {
           ip: "",
           hwv: "",
           ver: "",
           sid: ""
        };
        $(document).ready(function() {
          $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "http://192.168.55.146/command?XC_FNC=GetSI",
            timeout: 2000,
            error: function (err) {
                console.log("gateway error: check ip address and try
                            again");
            },
            success: function (data) {
                if(data) {
                    if(data.substr(0,8) === "{XC_SUC}") {
                        var jString = (data.slice(8));
                        var obj;
                        try {
                            var obj = JSON.parse(jString);
                        } catch(e){}
                        gateway.hwv = obj.HWV;
                        gateway.ver = obj.VER;
                        gateway.sid = obj.SID;
                        console.log(gateway);
                    }
                    else{
                        console.log("Error:" + "" + data);
                    }
                }
                else{
                    console.log("error with the gateway");
                }
            }
        });
     });
    </script>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```